# Joining two data.tables/data.frames with different structures but same content

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a two `data.table`s that were created by different operations, but values are the same. However, they have different structures as the output suggests:

```
> str(resultstabledata)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  234 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ pT      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Insignificant",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ shape   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Base","Comparison": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ resid   : chr  "minzer" "minzer" "minzer" "minzer" ...
 $ asset   : Factor w/ 3 levels "crude","gold",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ base    : Factor w/ 3 levels "mlp","elman",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ compared: Factor w/ 2 levels "arfima.roll",..: 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ N       : int  409 317 194 353 206 178 317 333 47 46 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> str(a)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ pT      : Factor w/ 4 levels "Insignificant",..: 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
 $ shape   : Factor w/ 1 level "Comparison": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ resid   : Factor w/ 2 levels "minzer","diff": 1 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ asset   : Factor w/ 1 level "crude": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ base    : Factor w/ 1 level "mlp": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ compared: Factor w/ 1 level "lame": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ N       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there a simple way how to do `rbind` on them and not relevelling the factors, because the level "captions" are by construction right?

To clarify what I am asking:
I am expecting behaviour like this. I have two data.tables/frames `a` and `b`. Both have variable `x` which is `factor` but in `a` 1->"bla", 2->"ble" and in `b` 1->"ble",2->"bla". Let's suppose structure `a$x` is `bla bla ble ble` and `b$x` is `ble ble bla bla`. By doing `merged <- rbind(a,b)` I would like to get `merged$x` is `bla bla ble ble ble ble bla bla`, but I am experiencing `merged$x` is `bla bla ble ble bla bla ble ble`.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It's nice to work with an example. Have you tried simply: `rbind(resultstabledata, a)`?

Comment: `rbind` does not work, as is suggested by the text I guess. I will work out some reproducible example later in the day.

Comment: I think you mean that in your first df, you've a label "Insignificant" assigned to 4 and in the second it's assigned to 1 and when you `rbind` them, they should not be releveled when you bind them? If so, then I don't think that's possible...

Comment: Interestingly it works when I convert the `data.table` to `data.frame` and factor from `a` to chr and `N` to int. Then levels are matched fine. Strange, I would expect `data.table` to behave like `data.frame`.

Comment: @Arun no, vice versa, when `rbind` applied, "Insignificant" from `a` turned to whatever had 1 in the `resultstabledata`.

Comment: But that is to be expected. If you do `rbind(a, resultstabledata)` then you'd see it get releveled the other way. You're asking for two levels for the same value.. isn't it?